# Proper way to write a complex objective and constraints in Python Pulp

Tags: python, linear-programming, pulp, operations-research

I am following a book that explains advanced linear programs. So far it's been good, but this example has me stumped on how to properly write the objective functions and constraints.

[image: linear program example]

Below you'll find my attempt at coding the left coefficient but as you can see it doesn't seem correct.

**My implementation so far is as follow**

```
   import pulp as lp

# data
r = 0.02
T = 2
J = 3
E = 6
K = {(1): 2, (2): 3, (3): 4, (4): 4, (5): 6, (6): 7}
C_j_t = {(1, 1): 2, (1, 2): 3, (2, 1): 4, (2, 2): 5, (3, 1): 6, (3, 2): 7}
F_j_e = {(1, 1): 2, (1, 2): 3, (2, 1): 4, (2, 2): 5, (3, 1): 6, (3, 2): 7}
I_j_e = {(1, 1): 2, (1, 2): 3, (2, 1): 4, (2, 2): 5, (3, 1): 6, (3, 2): 7}
# F_j_e = 1

prob = lp.LpProblem('Foobar Village Highway Problem', lp.LpMaximize)

X_j_t = lp.LpVariable.dicts("X",
                            [(j, t)
                             for j in range(1, J)
                             for t in range(1, T)],
                            cat='Continuous')

coef_left = {}                
for t in range(1, T):
    for j in range(1, J):
        coef_left[(j, t)] = (1 + r)**-t * C_j_t[(j, t)]

pv = (1 + r)**-T
right_side = {}
for j in range(1, J):
    for e in range(1, K[(j)]):
        right_side[(j, e)] = pv * F_j_e[(j, e)] * I_j_e[(j, e)]



prob += lp.lpSum(coef_left[(j, t)] * X_j_t[(j, t)] + right_side[(j, e)]
                 for j in range(1, J)
                 for t in range(1, T)
                 for e in range(1, E))


    prob.writeLP(r'8.2.1.lp')
    # Solve 
    prob.solve()
```

I don't think this is correct or that I'm using the right methodology to code this complex objective an constraint.

it returns the following:

```
\* Foobar_Village_Highway_Problem *\
Maximize
OBJ: 3.92156862745 X_(1,_1) + 7.8431372549 X_(2,_1)
Subject To
Bounds
X_(1,_1) free
X_(2,_1) free
End
```

Comment: Your objective is very different from the text. I would suggest staying closer to the formulas in the text. Also, do `print(prob)` instead of writing an LP file (so you don't lose any constant terms).

Answer (score 0):

We cannot reproduce much because the fragment is incomplete, but there seems an issue with the loop structure:

```
prob += lp.lpSum(coef_left[(j, t)] * X_j_t[(j, t)]
                 for j in range(1, J)
                 for i in range(1, T))  <----- for t
```

Comment: I updated my code with the whole objective function + output from it